# how to add child nodes in jquery nestable dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery nestable plugin to show my application organization -> Venue and Location tree structure. By Default I want to load the parent organizations only and when I click the expand button of any parent organization, I want to load venue of that organization with Ajax. Same will be process for N level locations which are under venue and my organization nestable tree should get reloaded.

The expand button is visible only if the parent node has children.

```
{foreach $organizations_list as $organization}
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
        <button type="button" data-action="load-venue" id="load-venue-{$organization.id}">Load</button>
        <div class="dd-handle"> 
            <span class="orange">{$organization.name} <small class="grey">(ID: #{$organization.id})</small></span>
            <span class="lighter grey">
                &nbsp; {$organization.description}
            </span> 
        </div> 
    </li>
{/foreach}
```